# Select count id_product for id_emp between some date

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I have a table in MySQL that shows the purchases from an employee using the id of a product. It shows the date where they do the purchase too.
Here's my problem, I want to do a select that count the number of products did the employees between some date.

An example of my table.

```
Time                     | Emp_id |  prod_id 
--------------------------------------------
2017-03-28 08:03:01.777  | 34     |  144  
2017-03-28 08:15:58.657  | 34     |  156  
2017-03-28 10:14:34.232  | 34     |  156  
2017-03-29 17:03:41.655  | 34     |  156    
2017-03-28 20:13:28.111  | 55     |  1090  
2017-03-28 16:45:17.777  | 55     |  1090  
2017-03-29 19:03:01.777  | 55     |  76
```

And I want to get all the purchases between 2017-03-28 and 2017-03-29 like this:

```
day        | employee | product | count
---------------------------------------
2017-03-28 | 34       | 144     | 1  
2017-03-28 | 34       | 156     | 2  
2017-03-28 | 55       | 1090    | 2  
2017-03-29 | 34       | 156     | 1    
2017-03-29 | 55       | 76      | 1
```

I don't really know how to do it, can anyone help me?

Comment: What have you tried so far?And what is the logic behind your result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a simple aggregation.

```
select date(time) as day,
    emp_id as employee,
    prod_id as product,
    count(*) as count
from your_table
where time >= '2017-03-28'
    and time < '2017-03-30'
group by date(time),
    emp_id,
    prod_id;
```

Comment: Why not use BETWEEN?

Comment: Because then I'll have to use `date(time) between date1 and date2` which will not be Sargable i.e. wouldn't be able to benefit if there are indexes available.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this by using the aggregate function `count()` and the [Date()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function in MySQL. This gets a count of all products for each employee by day:

```
select 
    Date(`Time`) as day,
    Emp_id,
    prod_id,
    count(*) as `count`
from Table1
where `Time` >= '2017-03-28'
    and `Time` < '2017-03-30'
group by Date(`Time`), Emp_id, prod_id;
```

Here is a [demo](http://rextester.com/SVUTB63425)